# Silverlight Version 4 latest build for Win7 64bit and WinXP 32bit

Tags: windows, silverlight

I have a requirement where a few people need the latest version of Silverlight 4 installed.

I know the latest version is 5.xx... but apparently with some new software we're having installed we have to use version 4.

After a bit of googling I can see that the latest version is Build 4.1.10329.0 Released May 8, 2012.

We have a mix of Win7 64-bit machines and WinXP 32-bit machines.

My questions:

- Is there a different version for each OS or the same one fits all? This seems strangely hard to decipher by googling.
- Does anyone know where I can download the latest version 4? Microsoft do not seem to offer it any more unless I'm just not finding it.
- Is there a separate browser version of it or will installing it also handle any browser needs? Our new software will be browser-based.

Comment: Well i'm now thinking that the latest version is probably a security patch - but how to get it?  I've also noticed Silverlight 4 appears incompatible with IE9 for what it's worth.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  It seems unwise to develop software that requires the client and/or customer to download Silverlight from a website not mantained by Microsoft.  Why don't you just build it against Silverlight 5 and maintain and only use Silverlight 4 code.

Comment: It is external software - i have no control over their development of it.  Apparently v5 will be supported from Jan 2013 onwards.  Meanwhile we need version 4.

Comment: Silverlight 5 runs Silverlight 4 software.  Microsoft only supports Silverlight 5 at this time.

Comment: unfortunately i'm told if we have silverlight 5 installed we'll get an error message and not get past the splash screen.

Comment: proved hard to find the latest version of silverlight 4 but not too hard to find a version 4 if you goggle away.  Passed it over to our IT dept to handle for now.